# Read from a Java InputStream with very large amounts of data multiple times

Tags: java, inputstream, bigdata

I would like to know what is the best way to read bytes from a Java `InputStream` multiple times and still be efficient when the stream is very large.
Let's say I have the following code:

```
public void handleBytes(InputStream in) {
    doStuff1(in);
    doStuff2(in);
    doStuff3(in);
}
```

where `doStuff1`, `doStuff2` and `doStuff3` all need to work on the same bytes but do different things. Also I am assuming that those functions can be asynchronous.

I know that it is possible to `mark` and then `reset` the stream but I am wondering if this is the way to go when `in` has a lot of data. Also if I want to have a thread worker per `doStuff-X`, I cannot really use `reset`.

Should I have a copy of the stream for each `doStuff-X` method? But then again I am not sure that it is going to be efficient for large amounts of data.

Comment: You need to provide more information about what the doStuff methods do.

Comment: If the input streams are not too large, then just load the bytes into memory, if you can and then run your various processes against the master set of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *know* that the three doStuff() functions are running asynchronously, then you could try using [Apache Commons IO TeeInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) to copy the contents of the initial InputStream to a [PipedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) that is connected to a [PipedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) that is being read by doStuff2().  Likewise you could set up a second TeeInputStream constructed using a second PipedOutputStream connected to a second PipedInputStream for doStuff3().

There are some restrictions on this approach:

1) doStuff1(), doStuff2() and doStuff3() must be running on separate threads or else you will buffer the entire file twice while doStuff1() is running and before doStuff2() and doStuff3() run.  This approach assumes that doStuff2() and doStuff3() are reading and processing data while doStuff1() is reading the data initially.

2) doStuff1() can't use use skip(), mark() or reset() as this will mess up the downstream functions (as outlined in the TeeInputStream javadoc.

This approach should be reasonably memory efficient so long as all three doStuff() functions can process data at about the same rate.

Comment: This seems to achieve what I want. But what do you mean in your first point when you say that the method assumes that doStuff2 and doStuff3 are reading and processing data while doStuff1 is reading the data initially. Why is that the case?

Comment: If the three functions are not running asynchronously (i.e. in separate threads), then doStuff2() and doStuff3() will not run until after doStuff1() is complete.  If they are not running and reading from the PipedInputStream while doStuff1 is running, then the data will accumulate in the pipe (which is essentially in memory although it may get written to disk, I'm not sure).  Since there are two pipes, you will be storing twice the data.  You indicated the data is "very large", so I am assuming you don't want two copies of it in memory.

Comment: That is why it is important to have the doStuff2()/doStuff3() functions running while doStuff1() is running.  It is so that while doStuff1() is adding data to the pipes those two functions (doStuff2()/doStuff3()) are simultaneously reading from the pipes (which clears the data from it).  Does that help?

Comment: Oh I see this makes a lot of sense. Cheers for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can only read an InputStream once without buffering up the entire input.

You could load it into memory if its a GB or so, or copy it to a file and replay it if you have many GBs.  If you can parse the data in one thread you can pass it to the other threads.

Comment: Copying it to a file seems to be a really easy way to do it. But I would need to write first all my bytes into a file before I can process them in the doStuffs methods.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this seems like a bad idea. `mark` is not guaranteed to be supported at all by the stream, and even when it is supported, you have to specify a limit how many bytes can be read before `reset` is called.

Since you mention that those `dostuff`s can be run asynchronously, why not start a thread for each of them and use queues to feed the input from the main thread into those three queues concurrently? It takes some synchronization, but this way you have no limit on the input volume and can still limit memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could adopt the PipedOutputStream and PipedInputStream.

```
static class Task extends Thread{
    private final String taskName;
    private final BufferedInputStream input;
    public Task(String taskName, PipedInputStream input){
        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.input = new BufferedInputStream( input);
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Thread "+this.taskName+" Start");

            final byte buf[] = new byte[8]; // 8 bytes for demo
            while(true){
                if( input.available() > 0){
                    input.read(buf);
                    System.out.println(String.format("Task Name %s, read:%s", this.taskName, new String(buf)));
                }
                else{
                    // TODO: Set break Condition:Ex: Check the expected read size
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try{
        final PipedInputStream input1 = new PipedInputStream();
        final PipedInputStream input2 = new PipedInputStream();
        final PipedInputStream input3 = new PipedInputStream();

        final Task t1 = new Task("Task1", input1);
        final Task t2 = new Task("Task2", input2);
        final Task t3 = new Task("Task3", input3);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        Thread.sleep(300);

        InputStream input = null;
        try{
            input = new FileInputStream("LargeInputFile.txt");

            final PipedOutputStream out1 = new PipedOutputStream(input1);
            final PipedOutputStream out2 = new PipedOutputStream(input2);
            final PipedOutputStream out3 = new PipedOutputStream(input3);

            byte buf[] = new byte[8]; // 8 bytes for demo
            while(true){

                if(input.available()>0){
                    int size = input.read(buf);

                    if(size > 0){
                        out1.write(buf);
                        out2.write(buf);
                        out3.write(buf);
                        out1.flush();
                        out2.flush();
                        out3.flush();
                    }                       
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Rread is finished!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        finally{
            if(input!=null){
                input.close();
            }
        }   
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```